# Algorithm for short IDs

Tags: encoding, base64, identifier

I'm looking for an algorithm - or should I better say: encoding? - to compress integer numbers to short string IDs like URL shorteners use: http://goo.gl/**0puu**

Url safe base 64 comes close to it, but maybe there is something better.

Requirements:

- as short as possible
- url safe

Comment: comes "close"? it's perfect...

Comment: Base64 is not "URL safe" per se.

Comment: @Cipi therefore the addition "url safe".

Comment: If your integers are big and you need fixed length string (which is smaller) and don't care if in some very rare cases *id* would have collisions, you may do `crop(base64(crc32(x)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"yi_H" called base64 "perfect" and after a bit more research I came to the same conclusion, since [only the following characters could be used in URLs without worry](http://urldecoderonline.com/url-allowed-characters.htm):

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 - _ . ~
```

Thats 66 characters, whereas [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) only uses 64 characters. The two more possible characters wouldn't be practical because 66 is not based on 2.

**Conclusion:** [URL safe base64](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64URLSafe%28byte%5b%5d%29) (offered as part of Apache Commons for example) is perfect for short IDs.